# including chapters in content list

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have no specific definitions in my latex file, I only use `\tableofcontents`. However, in the content list, the chapter names are not shown (I defined them by `\chapter{example}`).

How can I see the chapter names in the content list?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you run `pdflatex` twice? They should show up then, if they don't can you show a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I run now but it is still not there. What example? The chapter names that I define are not in the table of contents, only the sections and subsections...

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Take the code of your current document, remove as much as you can from it, without removing the problem, then edit your question to include that code.

Comment: Which document class do you use? `article`? Then you have error messages, but no chapters in the text and the TOC (not supported).  Please explain better what your problem is. Give as much information as possible to help us to help you ...

Comment: Thanks. I changed the class to report and run pdflatex twice. Now I have the chapters in the content list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the usual issue about compiling twice could be settled in comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments by changing to an appropriate documentclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your question does not show an minimal working example,  but I guess, that you use class `article` instead of `report` or `book`.  Class `article` does not know `\chapter`, which causes error messages in the log file you should see.

Change `article` to `report` or `book`, the the command `\chapter` can be used and the TOC contains also your used chapter headings ... Remember, that you have to compile twice or more to get the right TOC included ...

Without MWE I can not say more ...